# Inconsistent DataGridViewColumn width when AutoSizeMode set to Fill

Tags: c#, datagridview

I created a simple Windows Form App to replicate this problem. I created  a DataGridView1 and docked it onto Form1.

The DataGridView has 8 columns and each of them has this:

```
this.Column1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
this.Column1.FillWeight = 100F;
```

Whenever I resize the form, all the columns should be resized to equal width. But that is not the case, sometimes, some of the columns are smaller than the rest.

I printed out the column width when Form1 ResizeEnds and get the following results after 10 times of resizing:

```
private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        Console.Write(c.Width + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output：

```
67 67 67 67 66 67 67 67 
41 40 41 41 42 41 42 40 
144 145 144 146 145 145 145 143 
65 57 64 65 64 66 66 65 
27 26 26 26 26 27 27 23 
167 166 166 166 166 167 167 163 
49 50 49 50 47 49 51 51 
98 98 97 99 95 97 100 99 
34 25 33 34 33 34 34 35 
186 177 185 186 185 186 186 187
```

Its very frustrating to have this inconsistency and I hope there is a way to solve this. Thank you.

A screenshot of what the DataGridView looks like after resizing it multiple times:

[image]

Comment: Minor discrepancies should be expected. The `DataGridViewColumn.Width` is of type `int`. When the column widths are divided out from the full grid width, they may not divide evenly. Rather than lose the sum of floating point remainders, the columns are somehow adjusted in a way to compensate for this loss, hence: `41 40 41 41 42 41 42 40`. That said - I could not reproduce the significant differences you posted, such as: `34 25 33 34 33 34 34 35`. Thus the comment instead of an answer. Maybe there is other behavior not mentioned in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

Use a fixed font such as courier.

Pad the numbers with spaces so they have an equal length:

```
"888"  

" 88" 

"  8"
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the contents of the DataGridView. The columns AutoSizeMode is set to Fill, which means it will resize the column width based on the fill weight and the width of the DataGridView. If the fill weight for all columns are equal, I should get an almost equal width for all columns with a difference of not more than 1 taking into account the remainder after division.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `.AutoSizeMode` and use this code (sorry, this is `VB.NET` but I think you have no problem translate it in `C#`):

```
Private Sub YourForm_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.ResizeEnd

    Dim intRowHeadersWidthDefault As Integer = 41 'this is a default value; you can save it on form load

    Dim intVerticalScrollbarWidth As Integer = 0

    If Me.DataGridView1.Controls.OfType(Of VScrollBar)()(0).Visible Then
        intVerticalScrollbarWidth = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth
    End If

    Dim intBorderWidth As Integer = 0

    If Me.DataGridView1.BorderStyle <> BorderStyle.None Then
        intBorderWidth = 2
    End If

    Dim intSpaceToFill As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.Width - intRowHeadersWidthDefault - intVerticalScrollbarWidth - intBorderWidth

    Dim intColumnWidth As Integer = intSpaceToFill / 8

    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns(i).Width = intColumnWidth
    Next i

    Me.DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = intRowHeadersWidthDefault + intSpaceToFill - (intColumnWidth * 8)

End Sub
```

Basically this code force a column width to an integer and set row headers width to cover eventually remainder from space division.